# Maytag MDB9100 connector to circuit board

Tags: connector, cables, appliances

I'm replacing the circuit board on my Maytag MDB9100 dishwasher. I'm having trouble connecting the white and black connectors on the bottom edge of the new circuit board. Everything else has been fine.

The two connectors:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Post a picture of the new board that shows where the connectors are supposed to go.

Comment: Hi, Davide. I believe I answered your astute observation below. I don't need to post a photo - the new board does have the terminals where they're supposed to be. I inadvertently pulled the ones out of the old circuit board. They're very snug!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you did it to pull out the connectors so hard out of the ol;d board that you broke the solder joint and you pulled out the terminals from the PCB the way a dentist pulls out wisdom teeth from the jaw.  Ouch!

The new board should have quick-connect tabs in it. Right? You'll need to extract the quick-connect tabs from your white housings first. Then you'll be able to plug the white housing onto the quick-connect tabs on the new board.

Comment: Indeed, Davide, that is what I did. Once I looked at the old circuit board, I saw that the terminals were missing.  I've managed to pull one of the terminals out of the connector, but the other one is disintegrating as I work at it, so I'm not sure I have enough of the terminal sticking out of the connector to grab onto.  So frustrating - one connector away from finishing the repair! Thanks for your help. Really appreciate the quick reply.

Comment: Got it! And the repair is complete.

Comment: depending on the connector sometimes you need to squeeze them in a certain way to make them let go.